# flymake : How can I modify/ignore syntax and styling rules?

Tags: elpy, flymake

I'm using elpy to code in Python, along with flymake to help with style/syntax checking.

The problem being that I have my habit, and I like to sometimes put 2 blank lines between methods of the same class, which inevitably triggers the following :

`E303 : too many blank lines (2)`.

Now I'd like, or to have flymake ignore this specific error, or to edit the file where these rules are written, to trigger for instance a warning from 3 blank lines, and not 2.

How could I do that ?

Thanks.

Edit : I'm using GNU emacs 24.5.1 on Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`flymake` uses `flake8` to check the errors, so you have to tell `flake8` which errors you don't want to see. You can do that globally by creating the file `~/.config/flake8`, with the following content:

```
[flake8]
ignore = E303
```

You can also create a `setup.cfg` at the root of your project, with the same syntax, to have different settings per project.

Make sure to restart `flymake` after changing flake's config.

Comment: What if there are multiple rules that I want to ignore?

Comment: @alper you can use comma for that, like this: `ignore = E303,E304`

Comment: Just in case I end up here again [Configuring Flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html)