# Flymake: how can I modify/ignore syntax and styling rules?

Tags: lsp-mode, elpy, flymake

This question was asked before [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/40536/flymake-how-can-i-modify-ignore-syntax-and-styling-rules), but the solution doesn't work. It could be because I am not restarting `flymake` correctly.

The question is: how to have flymake ignore certain errors and warnings? The answer there was to have a file `~/.config/flake8` with

```
[flake]
ignore = E303
```

to ignore error `E303`. This is to ignore the error globally. I did this, but I didn't notice any changes. To restart `flymake`, I ran `flymake-start`, but still nothing happened. I didn't see an option that said `restart` for `flymake`. I tried with `flymake-mode`, but that also didn't do anything.

I have `elpy` for virtual environments, but I used `lsp-python` for code highlighting. I don't know if there could be a conflict there. `flake8` is installed in the virtual environment I have active. I am not sure what other information is relevant to solve this problem. Please let me know.

Comment: `flake8` (as of version 5?) no longer uses a global or user config. Just project-level configs or a file specified via command-line option. You'll probably have to adjust the options you're having `flymake` call `flake8` with.

Comment: How do I do that? I suppose I have the latest version, since I installed flymake and emacs from scratch just a couple of weeks ago. I am sorry my questions are dumb, but I am not emacs savvy.

Comment: That information is probably in the manual. https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/flymake/index.html#Top

Comment: [Configuring Flake8](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/configuration.html)